# Groupplots become misaligned with axis equal image

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I have several images I want to align in a groupplot environment. All of the images have the same width, whereas the images fall into two categories when it comes to height, one with "small height" and one with "large height". I have tried to plot them like this (top row are "large height", bottom row are "small height"):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        axis equal image,
        enlargelimits=false,
        axis on top,
        xmin=0.0, xmax=6, ymax=5,
        group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=0em, vertical sep=0em,
                     x descriptions at=edge bottom,
                     y descriptions at=edge left,},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[ymin=-5]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.0, xmax=6.0, ymin=-5.0, ymax=5.0] {image1};
    \nextgroupplot[ymin=-5]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.0, xmax=6.0, ymin=-5.0, ymax=5.0] {image1};
    \nextgroupplot[ymin=0]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.0, xmax=6.0, ymin=0.0, ymax=5.0] {image1};
    \nextgroupplot[ymin=0]
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.0, xmax=6.0, ymin=0.0, ymax=5.0] {image1};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the various images overlapping as can be seen below. If I remove `axis equal image`, I get correct alignment, but the images do not get the correct aspect ratio. Using `axis equal` instead of `axis equal image` gives correct alignment and aspect ratio, but leaves a lot of empty space in the top row (where the "large height" images are plotted) and makes the x ticklabels incorrect. How to solve this to get a nice, compact layout?

[image: Misaligned groupplots due to axis equal image]

Comment: You could set `x=1cm, y=1cm` instead of `axis equal image` to fix the alignment, but of course this means you're hard coding the dimensions...

Comment: @Jake: Thanks, that works well. I see your point about hardcoding the dimensions, but I'm fine with that. Another issue that came up: `x=.., y=..` is applied to my colorbar as well when I give it as an option to `\begin{groupplot}`. I fixed that by specifying it for each and every `\nextgroupplot` instead. Is there a way to "reset" `x=, y=` to their default, auto-calculated state?

Comment: Yes, you can reset the scaling just for the colobar by setting `colorbar style={x=,y=}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `x=1cm, y=1cm` instead of `axis equal image` to fix the alignment, if you're willing to hard code the dimensions.

If you want to use a `colorbar`, you can reset the scaling by setting `colorbar style={x=,y=}`.